# rename all columns dynamically with same name and numerical suffix

Tags: r, dplyr, rename

I want to rename all columns starting with S to this format :

original colnames

```
> colnames(df)
[1] "ID" "S31"         "S32"         "S33"         "S42"
```

to this:

```
> colnames(df)
[1] "id" "common_name_1"         "common_name_2"         "common_name_3"         "common_name_4"
```

I try with mutate_at but i don t find a way to generate automatic increasing suffix...
Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `rename_at` :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% rename_at(vars(starts_with('S')), ~paste0('common_name_', seq_along(.)))
```

---

Using base R, we can use `startsWith` :

```
cols <- startsWith(names(df), 'S')
df[cols] <- paste0('common_name_', seq_len(sum(cols)))
```

Or with `grep` :

```
cols <- grep('^S', names(df))
df[cols] <- paste0('common_name_', seq_along(cols))
```

Comment: perfect, thanks you, very helpful I didn' t know about seq_along()

Answer (score 1):

We can also use `grepl`

```
cols <- grepl('^S', names(df))
df[cols] <- paste0('common_name_', seq_len(sum(cols)))
```